# Raise PostgreSQL's NAMEDATALEN without recompiling

Tags: postgresql, character, constraints, limit, identifier

Is it possible to raise the identifier name limit, in PostgreSQL, to above 63 characters, without having to recompile all the database system? I have this Django project generating repeated index names because of this limit, and there's no way to change the model names because of my project's business requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a Django bug to me. An earlier bug, [maximum name length not specified for PostgreSQL](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13441), has been fixed. I'd expect Django to generate database identifiers that fit max_name_length(). Maybe I'm being unreasonably optimistic.

Django already knows to truncate and append a repeatable hash to fit Oracle's max_name_length(). (See [Naming Issues](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/databases/).) Surely they don't just throw together a long, compound identifier and hope for the best if you're using any other platform.

Is it possible you're overriding default behavior somewhere that's leading Django to ignore max_name_length()?

**Later** . . .

Actually, they just throw together a long, compound identifier and hope for the best. A thread on osdir.com suggests it will be fixed in Django 1.3. See [Problems with DatabaseCreation, table names, and index names - msg#00142](http://osdir.com/ml/django-developers/2010-03/msg00142.html)

**Still later . . .**

The ticket [Index length errors running tests on MySQL](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12977) shows that the same fix for MySQL was fixed in version 1.2. Also that PostgreSQL (and probably every other platform) had the same problem. I don't know whether a fix for PostgreSQL made it into 1.2.

Comment: Yes, it can be a Django bug... the version we were using was 1.2.3, and when I raised the max length (from 63 to 255) in Postgres then recompiled it, it worked. Don't know if it affects the 1.3 version though - and won't know, since I left my job last week. :-P

Comment: Well, I'll create a test project to do this and other tests, and try to simulate the conditions with newer versions of Django; When I have results, I'll post here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible, you must use shorter names. Other dbms's allow even less characters, you always have to check these constraints.

Comment: I disagree. A framework is supposed to abstract away platform-specific things like whether to use `TOP` or `LIMIT`, whether to use `EXTRACT` or `DATEPART()`, whether to delimit identifiers with single quotes, double quote, or brackets, and whether the maximum identifier length is 63 or 30. People use frameworks, in part, so they can *stop* thinking about the back end and focus on app development.

Comment: But when the framework doesn't do it, you have to start thinking again. The OP is asking how to change standard behaviour of the database, that's even worse than the bug in the framework! Fix the bug or pay attention to the names.